# Error with pandas dataframe (needs to be 1-dimensional)

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to determine the conformal predictions for my model with my data. But it gives me following error which occurs at icp.calibrate :

```
Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional
```

Below you can find the most recent traceback error about this. Unfortunately I am not sure on what this actually infers based on the code from above. I am using a pandas dataframe for this.

Code:

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from nonconformist.cp import IcpRegressor
from nonconformist.base import RegressorAdapter
from nonconformist.nc import RegressorNc, AbsErrorErrFunc, RegressorNormalizer, NcFactory
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Setup training, calibration and test data
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
df = pd.read_csv ("prepared_data.csv")


# Initial split into train/test data
train = df.loc[df['split']== 'train']
valid = df.loc[df['split']== 'valid']

# Proper Validation Set (Split the Validation set into features and target)
X_valid = valid.drop(['expression'], axis = 1)
y_valid = valid.drop(columns = ['new_host', 'split', 'sequence'])

# Create Training Set (Split the Training set into features and target)
X_train = valid.drop(['expression'], axis = 1)
y_train = valid.drop(columns = ['new_host', 'split', 'sequence'])

# Split Training set into further training set and calibration set
X_train, X_cal, y_train, y_cal = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size =0.2)

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Train and calibrate underlying model
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
underlying_model = RegressorAdapter(DecisionTreeRegressor(min_samples_leaf=5))
print("Underlying model loaded")
model = RegressorAdapter(underlying_model)
nc = RegressorNc(model, AbsErrorErrFunc())

print("Nonconformity Function Applied")
icp = IcpRegressor(nc)  # Create an inductive conformal Regressor
print("ICP Regressor Created")

#Dataset Review
print('{} instances, {} features, {} classes'.format(y_train.size,
                                                   X_train.shape[1],
                                                   np.unique(y_train).size))

icp.fit(X_train, y_train)
icp.calibrate(X_cal, y_cal)
```

#Example Dataframe

```
new_host  split     sequence    expression
FALSE     train     AQVPYGVS    0.039267878
FALSE     train     ASVPYGVSI   0.039267878
FALSE     train     STNLYGSGR   0.261456561
FALSE     valid     NLYGSGLVR   0.265188519
FALSE     valid     SLGPSNLYG   0.419680588
FALSE     valid     ATSLGTTNG   0.145710993
```

I've tried splitting the dataset in various ways but I am continuing to have trouble with this. In this case I want to split the data into train and test sets according to an observation's Data Split value. After which, I will split the train set into train and calibration in a second step. Where myfeatures, X_train and my target, y_train

#Traceback Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-68-083e5dd0b0b6> in <module>
      4 print(type(y_cal))
      5 print(y_cal.index)
----> 6 icp.calibrate(X_cal, y_cal)
      7 print("ICP Calibrated")

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nonconformist/icp.py in calibrate(self, x, y, increment)
    102                 else:
    103                         self.categories = np.array([0])
--> 104                         cal_scores = self.nc_function.score(self.cal_x, self.cal_y)
    105                         self.cal_scores = {0: np.sort(cal_scores)[::-1]}
    106 

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nonconformist/nc.py in score(self, x, y)
    370                         norm = np.ones(n_test)
    371 
--> 372                 return self.err_func.apply(prediction, y) / norm
    373 
    374 

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nonconformist/nc.py in apply(self, prediction, y)
    156 
    157         def apply(self, prediction, y):
--> 158                 return np.abs(prediction - y)
    159 
    160         def apply_inverse(self, nc, significance):

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in __array_ufunc__(self, ufunc, method, *inputs, **kwargs)
    633 
    634         # for binary ops, use our custom dunder methods
--> 635         result = ops.maybe_dispatch_ufunc_to_dunder_op(
    636             self, ufunc, method, *inputs, **kwargs
    637         )

pandas/_libs/ops_dispatch.pyx in pandas._libs.ops_dispatch.maybe_dispatch_ufunc_to_dunder_op()

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/common.py in new_method(self, other)
     62         other = item_from_zerodim(other)
     63 
---> 64         return method(self, other)
     65 
     66     return new_method

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/__init__.py in wrapper(left, right)
    503         result = arithmetic_op(lvalues, rvalues, op, str_rep)
    504 
--> 505         return _construct_result(left, result, index=left.index, name=res_name)
    506 
    507     wrapper.__name__ = op_name

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/__init__.py in _construct_result(left, result, index, name)
    476     # We do not pass dtype to ensure that the Series constructor
    477     #  does inference in the case where `result` has object-dtype.
--> 478     out = left._constructor(result, index=index)
    479     out = out.__finalize__(left)
    480 

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in __init__(self, data, index, dtype, name, copy, fastpath)
    303                     data = data.copy()
    304             else:
--> 305                 data = sanitize_array(data, index, dtype, copy, raise_cast_failure=True)
    306 
    307                 data = SingleBlockManager(data, index, fastpath=True)

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/construction.py in sanitize_array(data, index, dtype, copy, raise_cast_failure)
    480     elif subarr.ndim > 1:
    481         if isinstance(data, np.ndarray):
--> 482             raise Exception("Data must be 1-dimensional")
    483         else:
    484             subarr = com.asarray_tuplesafe(data, dtype=dtype)

Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional
```

Comment: You forgot to post the full error trace. Where exactly does the error pop up? Plus, question has nothing to do with `tensorflow` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: @desertnaut sorry for the inconvenience, the post has been updated

Comment: There is no `icp.calibrate(X_cal, y_cal)` command in your shown code. Please update the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pandas.DataFrame.drop() returns a pandas.DataFrame object which is inherently 2-dimensional. So when you assign `y_train = valid.drop()` you still have a 2-dimensional array (albeit only containing 1 column). On the other hand, pandas.Series object is 1-dimensional, and you can get a pandas.Series by referencing specific column (i.e. `valid['expression']` will return a 1-dimensional pandas.Series).

Change `y_train = valid.drop()` to `y_train = valid['expression']` and it should be ok.

Also, fyi, you're using *valid* DataFrame for X_train, y_train (I thought you might want to use *train* DataFrame)

Comment: would I be able to use something like this? `y_train = train.iloc[:,-1]` as well?

Comment: thanks for the update, this definitely was a positive change as my data.shapes have now changed `(X_train: (2924, 3); y_train: (2924,))` However, I am still getting the same error.

Comment: is it happening in the same place ? I didn't mention it, but obviously if you're doing something with y_valid make sure it's been changed similarly to y_train.

Comment: @dmt2 Yes it is happening in the same place, and I changed previously y_valid of course already before.

Comment: for some reason when I do this `y_train = y_train.to_numpy()` and the same for the y_valid set the error seems to be gone any reason to why?

Comment: I honestly don't know. Hope somebody is able to help.